# I cannot get GNU Root android application to install a simple gui

Tags: linux, fedora

Let me start off by saying I am not a master at the command line. I think it is old fashioned, but can at times be faster than a gui depending on what you need. It, by no means, can replace the ease of use a desktop/gui environment provides. I require my new Android tablet to run a few desktop games - classics like the original starcraft. I installed the GNU Root application and tried to first install a gui.

```
> sudo yum groupinstall "Kde Software Compilation"

sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0600, should be 0440

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

> sudo yum groupinstall "KDE Software Compilation"

sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0600, should be 0440

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

> sudo yum groupinstall "Xfce"

sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0600, should be 0440

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

> sudo groupinstall "Xfce"

sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0600, should be 0440

sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
>
```

I was using the Fedora distro and, if it makes any difference, the Terminal Emulator android application (i believe it is the only app by that name).